# Multi-user chat with history

Tags: chat, webapp-rec

Are there any web apps which allow multiple users to chat, while preserving the chat history for all to see?

Comment: "for all to see" - you mean public, or the users in the chat?

Comment: @Raithlin : for the users in the chat

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only ones I've found that don't totally suck, are ...

http://campfirenow.com/

http://talkerapp.com/

http://www.hipchat.com/

edit: and now **webapps very own chat!**

http://chat.webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ...and chat.meta.stackoverflow.com!

Comment: Any plan on offering the stack exchange chat engine for us to buy or to offer the same services as the others? or do you hate money?

Comment: (+1) for publishing Web application chat page.

Answer (score 1):

We now have our very own chat web-application!  Check out http://chat.webapps.stackexchange.com.

Comment: (+1) for publishing Web application chat page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Talk. All chats are archived within Gmail.

Comment: But does it do multi-user?

Comment: Of course it does. If not, it wouldn't qualify as an answer, would it? Just click on the icon with the person and the plus sign to add people to the chat.

Answer (score 0):

[Quassel IRC](http://quassel-irc.org) is not web app, but solve some problems
It is a modern, cross-platform, distributed IRC client, meaning that one (or multiple) client(s) can attach to and detach from a central core -- much like the popular combination of [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) and a text-based IRC client such as WeeChat, but graphical.

It allow multiple users connect to single core each with own accout, so in core keeps all chat logs. And again it just IRC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RumbleTalk](http://www.rumbletalk.com) online group chat. It is HTML5 (works on mobile) and it has archive, so you can search your chat history and even export it.

> RubmbleTalk lets you embed a free HTML5 online chat widget in websites, blogs, events, and Facebook pages. Choose your chat theme and talk from mobile or tablet.