# Preferred web based IRC application?

Tags: webapp-rec, chat, irc

I don't typically communicate via IRC and therefore don't keep a client installed. To keep from having to download a client I'd like to use a web based IRC service. What web based IRC clients exist and what is your favorite?

Comment: You might also be interested in http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/610/multi-user-chat-with-history

Comment: Try subway for Node.js (runs in your browser). It's awesome: https://github.com/thedjpetersen/subway

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Mibbit](http://chat.mibbit.com/) has a clean UI, doesn't require any plugins and has an embed feature.

Comment: Note that Mibbit doesn't work with Freenode. See http://blog.freenode.net/2009/06/new-freenode-webchat-and-why-to-use-it/ and http://blog.mibbit.com/?p=306

Comment: Mibbit also is probably unsupported by Quakenet, as they developed their own ads-free embeddable solution, [qwebirc](http://www.qwebirc.org/), available for [Quakenet](http://webchat.quakenet.org/) and [Freenode](http://webchat.freenode.org/)

Comment: Try this one: https://github.com/thedjpetersen/subway

Answer (score 3):

I have used the 3 preceding solutions, however I found that http://webchat.freenode.net/ seems to have the slickest (read:minimalist) interface and best feature set.

Comment: +1 for webchat.freenode.net . It's simple and useful. What package do they use?

Comment: It's [made on Quakenet](http://www.qwebirc.org/). Completely ads free.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [CGI::IRC](http://cgiirc.org/) installed on my own server to access IRC. It's not perfect, but it works and is free :)

Comment: If you need to host your own web IRC client, this is pretty much the only option I know for open source packages.  Unfortunately, it hasn't been updated since 2006.

Comment: Does it need updating? Does it have some security holes or something?

Answer (score 0):

On IRCNet and EFNet you can use this: http://webchat.xs4all.nl/index.php

http://chat.ircnet.org redirects over there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution which you can install to your own webserver, then an alternative to [CGI:IRC](http://cgiirc.org/) is [qwebirc](http://qwebirc.org/). A comparison:

- CGI:IRC is written in Perl; qwebirc is written in Python
- CGI:IRC requires a webserver (and runs as a CGI); qwebirc contains its own webserver (based on [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/)), running on its dedicated TCP port
- CGI:IRC uses one process per connection (may consume too much memory); qwebirc runs in a single process, no matter how many connections there are (so it uses much less memory)
- the latency per message (both incoming and outgoing) is very low for both CGI:IRC and qwebirc

Answer (score 0):

A newer tool I've run into is called [Alice](http://github.com/leedo/alice), which has a really nice and simple UI. If you don't want to run your own they're working on a hosted version.